# How can modle search in a matrix with bee algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use Bee algorithm for searching in a matrix.
for example we have an matrix with 100*100 size.
3 of it's fields are 1 valued and other ones are 0.
now how can we search this with Bee algorithm.
Thanks if help me.

The pseudo code for the bees algorithm :

1. Initialise population with random solutions.
2. Evaluate fitness of the population.
3. While (stopping criterion not met) //Forming new population.
4. Select sites for neighbourhood search.
5. Recruit bees for selected sites (more bees for best e sites) and evaluate fitnesses.
6. Select the fittest bee from each patch.
7. Assign remaining bees to search randomly and evaluate their fitnesses.
8. End While.

Comment: Could you give some more details?

Comment: If any field can be value 1, independent of any other field, the best thing you can do is a for loop them 1 by 1 to find them, unless you can remember them (hash them in a map) while they are being set.

If you want to learn (meta)heuristics like the Bee algorithm, use a better use case, such as N-Queens or ITC2007 examination.

Comment: thanks dear.we know classic ways take more time than this kind of algorithm.I am trying to implement a way to improve this time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the Bee algorithm is designed for continuous, rather than discrete data. So, it does not apply to your problem.